# Syntax of the type SortedDictionary<(Of <(<'TKey, TValue>)>)>..::..Enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax, msdn

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8z05h2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
SortedDictionary<(Of <(<'TKey, TValue>)>)>..::..Enumerator
```

is the return type in .Net 4.0 of the SortedDictionary GetEnumerator method. What in the world does this syntax mean. Certainly I am familiar with typical generics e.g.

```
public class MyClass<A,B> where A : C
```

but I don't know how to parse much of this declaration. What is `Of`, what is the the `'` before TKey for, are the parenthesis meant to improve readability or are they necessary and what is the `..::..` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Of" part is the VB way of doing generics. But this looks like a broken mixture of C#, VB, F# and C++.

The "Type" part of the docs is correct though - the return type of the method is

```
System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator
```

I suspect it was just a failure in whatever generates that bit of documentation. I suggest you  report it on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: And link the ticket here so we could participate

Comment: Never used Connect before. Can't find msdn listed as a product of any sort. Am I missing it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the reason is for that syntax in the msdn, but this is only confined to the msdn. There isn't a new syntax for generics.

Answer (score 0):

In C# that's mean:

```
SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator
```

In VB.NET:

```
SortedDictionary(OfType TKey, OfType TValue).Enumerator
```